# VBA Excel to MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

New to VBA, I am successfully importing and reading a Task List and Resources from Excel, executing VBA in Excel and inserting these records into MS Project. I am looking at setting the `ActiveProject.Resources.Standardrate = "100p/h"`, however I am getting an error.

The code being applied (credit to previous answers provided to other related questions on Stackoverflow for the following code).

```
If Not ExistsInCollection (newproject.Resources, strResource) Then
  newproject.resources.add.name = StrResource  <-- This works, resources are added.

  ' However, inserting the following line:

  newproject.resources.standardrate = "100p/h"  <-- It errors here

End if
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated - Thank you.

Comment: What error do you have an can you include a link to that other Stackoverflow post? That might make it easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needed a minor modification to get a reference to the newly-added resource so that the StandardRate can then be updated.

This code also demonstrates how to handle the case of a list of comma-delimited resources rather than a single one.

```
Dim t As Task
Set t = NewProject.Tasks.Add("New task 1")

Dim StrResource As String
StrResource = "Resource 1,Resource 2,Resource 3"
Dim arrRes As Variant
arrRes = Split(StrResource, ",")

Dim i As Variant
For Each i In arrRes
    If Not ExistsInCollection(NewProject.Resources, i) Then
        Dim r As Resource
        Set r = NewProject.Resources.Add(i)
        r.StandardRate = 100
    End If
    t.Assignments.Add , ActiveProject.Resources(i).UniqueID
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel, the Resource standardrate component has worked.

If I may ask an extension to the question. How would one handle if the (strResource) contains Resource Names that are (,) comma delimited? So that when the delimiter record is identified in the reference cell, a new resource record is then added to the Resource table in MSProject, as well as appending the total collective resources to the corresponding task being imported.

Example Cell data may include Resource #1, Resource #2, Resource #3. Insert them into the Resource table and assign them to task record being imported.